# Custom control box button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

Some Windows applications add buttons to the control box, which apparently is the name for the group of minimize, maximize, and close buttons. One such application is Skype, which has a button for switching from a one-window-that-contains-everything mode to a one-window-per-conversation mode and vice versa:

[image: Skype's custom control box button]

I'd like to know how you can do this. I've looked around and can't figure out how. I assume it would require P/Invoke and the Windows API, but I'm not sure what function I'd use.

Comment: I know this is bit old, but did You managed to add this? I'm looking for a solution to add extra button that will be styled same as other buttons (minimize, maximize, close). If it's possible please share Your code. Thanks

Comment: @Misiu: It’s been a while, but I think I asked this only out of curiosity and never actually implemented it in my application. The links in the accepted answer might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of these might be what you're looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/vb/transmenuandtitlebuttons.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/mintraybtn.aspx